# ng-repeat vertically and horizontally in a table when receiving dynamic data

Tags: angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to display data in a table.
Rows and columns are dynamic.
I want to use `ng-repeat`.

I am receiving data in this form:

```
headers: [
  0: {"heading1"},
  1: {"heading2"},
  2: {"heading3"}
]
```

```
data: [
  0:{ id:1, code:"Barry" , description:"Allen" }
  1:{ id:2, code:"Naruto" , description:"Uzumaki" }
  2:{ id:3, code:"Hannah" , description:"Montana" }        
]
```

I tried this way :

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td ng-repeat="c in headersData">
      {{c}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="c in columnData">
    <td>{{c.id}}</td>
    <td>{{c.code}}</td>
    <td>{{c.description}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

But it's not rendering the `thead`.
Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[])
app.controller('MainController',function($scope) {
   $scope.headersData =  [
 "heading1",
 "heading2",
 "heading3"
];
 $scope.columnData =  [
  { id:1, code:"Barry" , description:"Allen" },
  { id:2, code:"Naruto" , description:"Uzumaki" },
  { id:3, code:"Hannah" , description:"Montana" }        
] ;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testApp">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="4.0.0" 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.min.js">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainController">
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th ng-repeat="th in headersData">{{th}}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in columnData">
    <td>{{x.code}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you receive an array like in the headers case, you must define a var name for key and value pair. Try this:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td ng-repeat="(key,c) in headersData">
      {{c}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="c in columnData">
    <td>{{c.id}}</td>
    <td>{{c.code}}</td>
    <td>{{c.description}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is a wrong way of doing.
There is a way where you can use `ng-repeat="(key,value) in yourjson` format.

So check that out first.

And your headers should not be declared in such a way. or in other words, should not be rendered in such a way. you are doing `c in headers` which will give you objects. `{heading1 }` and so on.
This is a very basic question with so many answers already available in Stack Overflow.

So do something like, 
`ng-repeat="x in headers"`

and define your headers as 
`headers= ["heading1","heading2","heading3"]`
as the one you have declared is not a valid JSON.

To check validity of JSON, you can check out [JsonLint](https://jsonlint.com/).

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was repeating the `<tr><th>` instead of only the `<th>` values.

Non-working

```
                <thead>
                    <tr *ngFor="let item of tableColumns">
                        <th>{{ item }}</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
```

Working

```
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th *ngFor="let item of tableColumns">{{ item }}</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
```